# kinect xbox 360

Tags: ros-hydro, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
There are many questions about kinect installation in ROS community and my question is not original in it. But... I would like to sum up my understanding about this problems by asking the question:
Am I right that drivers of sensor "kinect xbox 360" model 1414 does NOT install to ubuntu 14.02 precise, Hydro distribution?

It is true that I am not UNIX guru and sometimes I can not think out how to modify commands likes experienced users. Anyway, I figured out that many manuals are outdated currently and the files are edited in the repositories. I meant the manuals: http://blog.ethanlim.net/2013/08/installing-openni-nite-sensorkinect-on.html, http://a-asvadi.ir/install-kinect-xbox360-ubuntu-12-04/,http://igorbarbosa.com/articles/how-to-install-kin-in-linux-mint-12-ubuntu/ and etc.

Also, I can not understand theoretically the relation between Hydro distribution and the kinect driver. Is the relation there?

Pls, give me an advice what I can do for installation kinect xbox 360 driver or kinect for microsoft on ubuntu. It is possible to reinstall another ROS distribution and ubuntu version, if it will be needed.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211931/kinect-xbox-360/) by [dyupleks](https://answers.ros.org/users/22089/dyupleks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 200 on 2015-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use ROS Indigo but I hope it works the same way for ROS Hydro
You need to install freenect_stack package :

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-freenect-stack
```

Then you should be able to launch the Kinect :

```
roslaunch freenect_launch freenect.launch
```

After this is launched you will be able to see topics related to the RGB, depth...

---

Originally posted by [Arowana](https://answers.ros.org/users/22294/arowana/) with karma: 381 on 2015-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2